# Self join left outer (all from first matching from second)

Tags: join, pyspark, left-join, outer-join

How do I join a dataframe with itself using `left outer (all from first matching from second)`?

Not sure if this is correct

```
df.alias('d1').join(df.alias('d2'), how = 'leftouter')
```

**Edit 1**

```
df = spark.read.parquet(file)
dfSort = df.sort(col('ID').asc(), col('Date').asc())

dfIndex = dfSort.withColumn('Index', monotonically_increasing_id())
                .withColumn('IndexNext', col('Index')+1)
                .withColumn('AccountIndex', concat(col('ID'),lit('-'), col('Index')
                .withColumn('AccountIndexNext', concat(col('ID'),lit('-'), col('IndexNext')
                .drop('Index', 'Index Next')

dfJoined = dfIndex.alias('d1').join(dfIndex.alias('d2'), df1.AccountIndexNext == df2.AccountIndex, 'leftouter').dropDuplicates()
```

This takes a while to run but does it make sense?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, at least to me.... but if you want to have all values in the first column with all the values in the second column, it works... only consider delete the duplicated values

Comment: Thanks @SamirHinojosa PowerBI has this option to use `left outer (all from first matching from second)` so I want to implement the same in PySpark.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
data = [("JUAN","CHINTAN"), 
        ("JHON","USER"), 
        ("LAURA","CARLA"), 
        ("HELOISE","STEVE"),
        ("CALI","JULIA"), 
        ("STALIN","JULIA"), 
        ("DAVID","MATH")
      ]

dataColumns = ["A","B"]
dataDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=dataColumns)

dataDF.show()

+-------+-------+
|      A|      B|
+-------+-------+
|   JUAN|CHINTAN|
|   JHON|   USER|
|  LAURA|  CARLA|
|HELOISE|  STEVE|
|   CALI|  JULIA|
| STALIN|  JULIA|
|  DAVID|   MATH|
+-------+-------+
```

After merging

```
dataDF.select("A").join(dataDF.select("B"), how = 'leftouter').dropDuplicates().show(50)
+-------+-------+
|      A|      B|
+-------+-------+
|   JUAN|CHINTAN|
|   JUAN|  STEVE|
|   JUAN|   USER|
|   JUAN|  JULIA|
|   JUAN|   MATH|
|   JUAN|  CARLA|
|   JHON|CHINTAN|
|   JHON|   USER|
|   JHON|  CARLA|
|   JHON|  JULIA|
|   JHON|   MATH|
|   JHON|  STEVE|
|  LAURA|   MATH|
|  LAURA|  STEVE|
|  LAURA|   USER|
|  LAURA|  JULIA|
|  LAURA|CHINTAN|
|  LAURA|  CARLA|
|HELOISE|   USER|
|HELOISE|  JULIA|
|HELOISE|   MATH|
|HELOISE|CHINTAN|
|HELOISE|  CARLA|
|HELOISE|  STEVE|
|   CALI|CHINTAN|
|   CALI|  JULIA|
|   CALI|   MATH|
|   CALI|  STEVE|
|   CALI|  CARLA|
|   CALI|   USER|
| STALIN|   MATH|
| STALIN|   USER|
| STALIN|  STEVE|
| STALIN|  JULIA|
| STALIN|  CARLA|
| STALIN|CHINTAN|
|  DAVID|   USER|
|  DAVID|  STEVE|
|  DAVID|  JULIA|
|  DAVID|CHINTAN|
|  DAVID|   MATH|
|  DAVID|  CARLA|
+-------+-------+
```

As I mentioned before, consider using **.dropDuplicates()**

Comment: I have put full code in edit. Please see if it makes sense.

Comment: Could you please provide some of the data and also the output expected? so, I can see what you want